# OpenApi. Require user to always set Content-type in request's header

Tags: rest, yaml, openapi

I'm implementing a PATCH endpoint and I want to be sure that different RFCs are correctly defined. Over all I don't want allow requester to miss the Content-type field in header.

My OpenApi spec `.yml` file looks like this:

```
parameters: (...)
requestBody:
  description: Some description here...
  required: true
  content:
    application/json-patch+json:
      schema:
        $ref: some-valid-shcema-reference-here
responses: (...)
```

The outcome for this:

1. When requester sets in header `Content-type: application/json-patch+json`, he's not returned with 400, code in controller behind is executed --> This is what I want
2. When requester sets in header a `Content-type value different than application/json-patch+json`, he's returned with 400 --> This is what I want
3. When requester doesn't set any `Content-type` value, he's NOT returned with 400, code in controller behind is executed --> **This is NOT what I want**

Two questions:

1. **How can I require user to always set Content-type?** (something like "require" flag for parameters)
2. Why the specified Content-type is used by default?

Comment: That might depend on your framework and controller code. Which framework do you use?

Comment: I'm using AWS lambdas and making a validation with "openapi-enforcer". But I'm not quite sure that this could be relevant to my question, as I'm looking for the correct way to define what I want in specs, regardless who will validate requests to meet the specs. I know I could do the workaround of checking it in my controller.